# Copy file from folder if not exist in a different folder with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to copy all the files from a folder if they do not exist in a different folder with a batch file. This is what I have so far.

```
for %%F in ("p:\Ferm batch reports\*.*") do if not exist "\Staging$\NgeBatchRecipeOriginal" copy %%F "\Staging$\Ferm batch reports\"

for %%F in ("p:\Yeast Prop batch reports\*.*") do if not exist "\Staging$\NgeBatchRecipeOriginal\" copy %%F "\Staging$\Yeast Prop batch reports\"
```

When I run this, it does nothing.

Comment: Try the command in the `for` body manually for a single item and check your path specifications, which I think are incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

Macro %~nxf extract only filename with extention:

```
for %%f in (dir1\*.*) do if not exist "Dir2\%%~nxf" copy %%f Dir3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... copy %%F ...
```

because %%F contains spaces, `copy` interprets it as a few Parameters instead of one with spaces.

Change it to

```
... copy "%%F" ...
```

Comment: I'd go for `"%%~F"` as this avoids double-double-quotes in case `%%F` already contains a pair of double-quotes...

Comment: @aschipfl in general, you are right, but with this `for` command, `%%F` won't have quotes.

Comment: I agree, but I always recommend `%%~F` for file paths in general though, even if it might not make a difference in a certain case... ;-)